# Install a list of Python projects (with pip) programmatically from Python code

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have a list of Python projects (libraries) such as:

```
libraries = ['numpy', 'pandas', 'matplotlib', 'torch', 'gensim', 'cv2', 'tpot', 'librosa']
```

I would like to get these installed from within Python code (similar to `pip install libraries`) while ignoring potential failures. How do I proceed with such a task?

Comment: Do you know about [_pip_'s `requirements.txt` files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files)?

Comment: create a requirement.txt file and you can install once

Comment: @MohammadAarif
Thanks a lot, guys I tried with requirements.txt initially but I'm unable to use try-catch to avoid "No matching distribution found" error. By any chance can we pass this error.

Comment: @sinoroc
I tried with requirements.txt initially but I'm unable to use try-catch to avoid "No matching distribution found" error. By any chance can we pass this error.

Comment: so if you want to achieve your requirement  as you have explained you have to use a loop

Comment: @Chiru Do you want to do the install from the command line (bash, shell, etc.) or from Python code (script, module, application, etc.)?

Comment: @sinoroc I'm using jupyter notebook to install em'. Anyhow bash commands can be utilized inside a jupyter notebook. I have hundreds of libraries to be installed, Is there any way that I can install them all with a command and ignore the errors caused by some third party libraries in between.

Comment: Yes there are for sure some solutions. I think you should rephrase your question though, since it has been closed (wrongly, from my point of view, since suggested similar questions have subpar answers). Maybe state clearly in the question that you want to install from within Python code (not from the command line) and can't or won't use a `requirements.txt` file, because you want to skip over failed installations.

Comment: @ChiruHarshith We haven't managed to get the question reopened, so I will try to answer here... First make sure to read ["Using pip from your program"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program). You would probably want to iterate over the `libraries` list (`for library in libraries:`)and do something like `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', library])` in a `try:` clause to catch or ignore specific exceptions, so that the installation continues with the next library in case one fails.